# EaselJS how to change dynamic text inside a clip

Tags: createjs, easeljs, adobe-animate

I have a clip with 3 frames.
Every frame has a Dynamic Text object.
I need to change dynamically those text contents.
But... if I change the text, for example with instruction:

```
my.object.text = "new content";
```

I see in console log that this instruction take effect, but if I use the `.gotoAndStop()` to change the frame, the text inside my Dynamic Text objects come back to the original value (edited inside Adobe Animate).

There is a way to change it dynamically?

Comment: I don't think so. The text object is part of the clip so it will advance in frames when you call .gotoAndStop(). If you set .text you will set it only for the current frame, not the whole clip.